# How does multi dimensional array in C work

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I am creating a C program with tables in it using multi dimensional arrays that is used to store two letters and a number as follows:

```
int main()
{
    char x[5][3];
    int y[5];

    for (i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        printf('Enter the 2 characters for x');
        scanf('%s', x[i]);

        printf('Enter number for y');
        scanf('%d', &y[i]);
    }
}
```

What I don't understand here is in the `for` loop. For example, for the iteration `i=0`, if the user enters two characters say `A`,`B` where do these letters get stored in the memory location of `x`? I mean is it at the position `x[0][0]` or `x[0][1]` or some other location?

I know it might be a silly question but I am really confused here.
Thank you for the help in advance.

Comment: I find it surprising that no one mentioned that you used `'` instead of `"` in both the `printf`s, and the `scanf`s.

Comment: "_I mean is it at the position x[0][0] or x[0][1] or some other location?_" -- Yes. `A` at `x[0][0]` and `B` at `x[0][1]` and the NUL-terminator at `x[0][2]` (automatically written by `scanf`)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The thing is that here you have a two-dimensional array of char meaning that in one memory location you cannot store more than one single character. So it will be stored in position 0 and 1. However I think your approach is not correct.

In your case you either want to store char* so that your array would be something like:

```
char* tab[5] ;
```

And you'll need to allocate memory for each line with:

```
tab[i] = (char *) malloc ( 2 * sizeof(char));
```

Or you can keep your array and instead do (if you want to be sure of what's happening in memory):

```
for (i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    printf("Enter the first character for x");
    scanf("%c", &x[i][0]);
    printf('Enter the second character for x');
    scanf("%c", &x[i][1]);
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: You could mention: `char* tab[5]` should be `char* tab[5];` and Not to cast the result of `malloc`

Comment: Thanks, didn't see that. Editing right now. However, malloc result should always be cast

Comment: Your code has issues. 1) [Don't cast the result of `malloc`](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) 2) `printf` and `scanf` expects a `const char*` (string literal) as their first argument, not multi-character literals 3)You scan the characters into a `char` (while `%c` in the `scanf` expects a `char*`).

Comment: Agreed with the last two points yet do not agree with the cast. Though not necessary, casting the result of malloc is better for portability with older versions AND with c++. That is also mentioned in the post you link to.

Answer (score 4):

A multidimensional array in C is a one-dimensional array elements of which are in turn arrays.

For example if you have an array defined like

```
char x[5][3];
```

you can rewrite its definition the following way

```
typedef char T[3];
T x[5];
```

So now array `x` looks like a one-dimensional array with type `T` where `T` in turn has type `char[3]`

Taking this into account there is no difference between using array `x` and array `y` in the program loop.

```
for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
{
    printf('Enter the 2 characters for x');
    scanf('%s', x[i]);

    printf('Enter number for y');
    scanf('%d', &y[i]);
}
```

The both arrays have `5` elements. The only difference that elements of array `x` have type `char[3]` and elements of array `y` have type `int`.

Because format specifier `%s` is used to enter a string in a character array and each element of array `x` is indeed a character array of type `char[3]` then each time when the loop iterates each array `x[i]` gets its own string.
For example after entering values to the array it could look for example like it is defined the following way

```
char x[5][3] =
{
   { "AB" }, /* x[0] */
   { "CD" }, /* x[1] */
   { "EF" }, /* x[2] */
   { "GH" }, /* x[3] */
   { "IJ" }  /* x[4] */
};
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31286930/how-does-multi-dimensional-array-in-c-work#comment50567737_31286930

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will get store in x[0][0] and x[0][1] location.

While `scanf` a string we need to give starting address of `character Array's` memory location which is in your code is `x[i]`

Answer (score 1):

In your example, they will get stored at `x[0][0]` and `x[1][0]` respectively.
Also you might want to change `scanf('%s', x[i]);` to `scanf('%c', x[i]);` as you are taking only a character.

Answer (score 0):

It's a **pointer** so, If the user enters the string "AB", "AB" will be allocated in the memory and your first case of your array will points on the first case allocated for the string :

```
... | 45 | 46 | 47 | 48 | ...
    ---------------------
    |  x |  A | B  |  x |
```

x[0][0] will points on case 46 for example.